# Using all the div width when using imshow with dash

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am working on an application with Dash. It has a really simple layout: a main area with a viewer and a left column with the controls. I am using Plotly express imshow in order to display the image. The figure is occupying all the width of the main area, but the 'canvas' is centered and keeps the image's original aspect ratio. In the example shown below the image is zoomed in, and as you can see there are black bars on the sides. I would like to use all the main area for the viewer.

[image: Current viewer with black bars.]

The code used to create this figure is:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pydicom as dic

img = dic.read_file('front/assets/test_img.dicom').pixel_array

fig = px.imshow(img, binary_string=True, template='plotly_dark')
fig.update_yaxes(
    ticklabelposition="inside top",
    title=None,
    ticks="inside", 
    ticklen=10,
    tickcolor='white',
    minor_ticks="inside")

fig.update_xaxes(
    ticklabelposition="inside",
    title=None,
    ticks="inside",
    ticklen=10,
    tickcolor='white',
    minor_ticks="inside")
fig.update_layout(margin=dict(l=0, r=0, t=0, b=0, autoexpand=False))
```

I would like to move the left rule to the left and use all the area when zooming in, with independence of the image aspect ratio.

Comment: So, what do you want?  Do you want the image to fill the area even if it distorts the picture?  Do you want the top and bottom to be cropped?

Comment: I want to, when zoomed, use all the available space.